# How do you compile C# code using mono embedded in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, mono, monodevelop

#### How do you compile .cs files using C++

I have searched all through Mono's documentation and can't find a way to just compile C# code from the embedded mono runtime in C++. I know how to open a C# `.exe` assembly file using the embedded mono functions from C++, but I can't seem to find a way to just compile a `.cs` file to the `.exe` from C++.

I have also managed to compile the `.cs` files by calling the `mcs.bat` file from the CreateProcessA() function that Windows provides, however this does not give me a way to log errors or even check if it succeeded in compilation etc. (It also feels like a *hack* and not the official solution). The main reason I need to do this is so that I can recompile C# scripts on the fly by detecting when the source code has changed and another subset of conditions.

Does anyone know of a way to properly compile C# files using the embedded Mono runtime? And where to find the documentation for this? Currently I've been using the documentation here: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3adeploy%2fmono-api-assembly.html which provides enough information for the most part.

#### Linking Mono in a DLL

Also, if you're familiar with embedding mono, do you know how to use it in a dll? I've managed to successfully link and compile it within a console application, but when I try to compile it as a part of a dynamic library, I get unresolved external symbol errors (specifically functions with the prefix __imp*).

Lastly, I'm using mono to embed C# as a scripting language for my game engine, however I don't know if there is a better (smaller) solution that I can use. If you know of any better solution feel free to leave a recommendation.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here. Do you want to cross-compile C# to C++, compile C++ with Mono (for example as a DLL), or something else completely? A `.cs` file is C#, but you want to compile it with C++?

Comment: Hey @kettle3D I'm trying to compile the C# file within C++. It looks like the only way to compile C# using mono is by using mcs.bat, but I was wondering if they provide a method in the embedded runtime to do that as well. It doesn't make sense to me that they would give you the ability to load compiled C# scripts using their embedded API, but not give a way to also compile them. Does that make sense? If not I can add some code snippets with a bit more details. Ah I just realized I had a typo in the intro of the question too which may have led to some confusion

Comment: The runtime is just runtime. If you need to compile C# code, you need to host a compiler such as Roslyn.

Comment: @LexLi Roslyn looks very promising, and I guess it makes sense to have a separate library for runtime and compilation, however it seems very heavyweight. I know that C# is a heavyweight scripting language regardless, however is this the typical approach to embedding a language using mono? I can't find many resources that talk about best practices when it comes to embedding a scripting language and just want to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid. Thanks for your help too!

Comment: @LexLi I was thinking about this for a minute though. and mono does come with a compiler (mcs.exe)... I just don't understand why they would expose their runtime API but not the compilers API, unless I'm missing something here

Comment: That's because typical Mono embedding is runtime only. Unity used to host Mono that way (but later switched to their private hosting approach), and CryEngine also hosts the runtime only. People compile C# apps to MSIL separately, and then the runtime executes MSIL. Mono's mcs is obsolete, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c

Comment: Thanks again @LexLi you're article was very informative. I'm going to have to do more research into the history of .NET, but it looks like Roslyn is definitely the way to go for me!

Answer (score 0):

The mono runtime is a "Runtime", only for running the code,
but if you have installed the `csc` command then you can use this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
   system("csc yourfile.cs")
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `The mono runtime is a Runtime, only for running the code` Not true, It can be easily done using internal compiler.